How does the forum feel about being asked to debug program code?
In the last few days, we have had 3 different questions which have the basic structure of "please debug this program for me", followed by a lot of code.  In one case over 600 lines, in another one over 460 lines.  The third case mercifully said that the code was too long to post.
Are such questions on topic?
We've probably had good questions in the past about the meaning of short code sequences, but this seems to be a new and recent thing. It's not the same as asking "how do I do $WHATEVER", it's being asked to look at actual code that purports to do it but fails, or to explain how the program works.

See also: Should we have retro-coding questions on Retrocomputing?

Related, but not quite the same thing.  Programming questions on old languages or old hardware, sure.  Posting several hundred lines and asking for them to be debugged/explained, not so much.

There's some discussion of debugging in Are x86 programming questions on-topic? – Chenmunka wrote “If the wording of the question specifically related to understanding some feature of old assemblers that is different to modern practice then it would be on topic. However, I don't believe we should be a debugging service.”. If you have an opinion, it's fine to self-answer a meta question.

Ah, I missed that particular sentence. Thanks.

@wizzwizz4 I would agree as well.

This recent question is largely a debug-my-code question.

I assume it's these two question you've referring to:

Flickering screen when pressing 'S' key in 8060 assembly program
What does this triangle rasterization code do? What does it use a “depth cueing table” for?

While the first one can be seen with some good will as retro by being a 16 bit COM program, it's still a generic debug my program question; the second in turn completely leaves this territory by being a high level, machine independent algorithm coded in C. It's pure CS theory and as far from retro as it gets.

I would agree that the core component of this question is already covered in several answers to the question:  Are x86 Programming Questions on Topic. Maybe a bit indirect. So it may help to point it out more directly:
RC.SE is not a debugging service.
The very same way as RC.SE is not a homework service.
There will always be a class of questions where the core is hard tied to a classic hardware, software or combination thereof. And those are not only fine, but very welcome. So we need to filter and protect them.
I do not think that size or language does really make a point for on/off-topicness. What does is how the problem approached and presented: I would expect the problem being analysed and broken down to a level that excludes generic CS and obvious debugging issues and presents a state the one asking can not explain, because the asked for component is not obvious using today's common knowledge (*1).
Using such a common sense classification could easy rule out all four of the questions mentioned. Fair rules/judgement are rarely about form or size but need o look at content and meaning.

*1 - This also means showing basic research, like what an address on the CPU programmed is, or that Assembler really executes straight ahead ...

I would be wary of accepting such questions.
An ideal question asks about a single, more-or-less timeless, commonly encountered issue (or a few very closely related issues).  Many debugging questions fail to meet this standard.  What tends to happen is that there are several unrelated things going wrong at once that need to be separately explained, so the answers become disjointed, with some only addressing some of the problems.  A later reader, even one who encounters at least one of the same problems the original asker had, will have to weed out irrelevant details.  Or the reason for the program not working turns out to be a silly typo that will never happen again the exact same way to anyone else.  Either way, the question turns out to be useful to nobody but the original asker: its value to the Q&A library is low to negligible.
These problems are not inevitable: a skilled programmer will be able to spot typos, isolate each individual problem they encounter and ask about them separately – although in that case, they often need not cast the question as a debugging problem at all.
In the end, each debugging question will have to be individually evaluated.  Some of them will be acceptable – for example, https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/revisions/21549/1 was originally asked pretty much as a debugging question, but since it had in its core a commonly applicable topic, I think it should be allowed.  But in the case of particularly messy or trivial ones (like typos), I will support having them closed as unfocused or out of scope.

Yes they are on topic, otherwise we have to try to define a maximum number of lines of code we are willing to accept.
Clearly, ten lines of Z80 assembler is going to be no problem, whereas 300 lines of COBOL is no fun at all!
I propose people upvote questions they like, downvote questions they don't like and let the wisdom of the crowd be the judge.

Why do we have to make the threshold "lines of code"? Are there no other methods of discrimination?

Is it? I'd say 300 lines of COBOL is even more fun!

"Lines of code" is to me a proxy for a lack of effort in isolating whatever the problem might be.  In a similar way, we don't have a quantifiable threshold for how much detail is "too little", but we are still willing to close questions for having too little detail. Mostly, we know it when we see it, and we have a large enough membership to smooth out any localized biases.

Come to that, I bet we'd have a de facto lines-of-question restriction if we started getting questions whose length exceeded what the average RC member was willing to bother with.
